# OleDbDataAdapter.Fill uses String for Date datatype

Tags: .net, t-sql, ole

When using an OleDbDataAdapter to fill a DataTable or DataSet, connecting to a SQL 2008R2 database, columns with the Date datatype are represented as Strings not DateTime in the resulting table.

Does anyone know why, and if it is possible to fix it other than casting it to a datetime in my query?

When I look at [MS's site on Data Type Support for OLE DB Date/Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677303(v=sql.105).aspx), it says that the it supports DBTYPE_DBDATE for Date, but the DataType of the resulting data column is String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else ever has a similar issue:

The application was using the provider SQLOleDb, when I changed that to SQLNCLI11 it worked.  I haven't yet figured out why SQLOleDb doesn't work.  I believe it has something to do with SQLOleDb being mainly used for ADO (not ADO.NET).